# Flex: Is there any way to show scroll bars on a Container when children are off the top/left?

Tags: apache-flex, scroll, containers

If I've got a Container with a child component that is off either the top or the left hand side:

[button off the top left http://img.skitch.com/20100318-hbknmsx34thu7gc1asarjis4m.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100318-hbknmsx34thu7gc1asarjis4m.png)

Is there any way to get scroll bars to show up? ie, so I can scroll up and get the button back in view, the same way I could if the button was off the bottom right side?

Thanks!

Comment: you can force the horizontalScrollPolicy and the verticalScrollPolicy to On, but I don't think it allows your scrollpositions to be negative.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately you're right - the scroll bars will show, but they won't go negative.

Answer (score 1):

I've never really had a need for this, nor tried it, but you could try setting the scroll policies to On and then setting minScrollPosition to a negative number on the horizontalScrollBar and verticalScrollBar properties of the Container.